# Azure APIM - Administrator groups by Products?

Tags: azure-api-management

I am not seeing a way to do this. But I would like to create separate Administrator groups per Product in Azure APIM. Please note, this is to design the APIs...not to subscribe/consume. At the moment there is a single Administrators group that can design all APIs, Products, etc. But if I have different IT systems and would like to segment the design ownership of these individual Products to different groups, is there a way to achieve this using a single APIM instance?

So lets say,

1. Product: 'ERP' with AAD Administrators group 'ERP IT Developers'
2. Product: 'SharePoint' with AAD Administrators group 'SharePoint IT Developers'
   etc.

Right now it appears like its not possible to do this split. Am I correct?

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried implementing the restriction at the product level?

1. Check your user list.

[image]

2. Create a group with by selecting the required members.

[image]

3. Create an product( Add required APIs) -> Go to access control -> Add a group (you may remove the Administrator group)

[image]

You may check the standalone subscription https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions#subscriptions-for-all-apis-or-an-individual-api - if this suffices the requirement

Comment: Jaya - Thanks for the response! I might be wrong about this, but isn't doing it this way mainly for visibility on who can view the Product in the Developer Portal? Can the user added this way actually design the policies for the underlying APIs (each API having its own developer)? If I have a couple of people designing ALL APIs then no issue as there are no boundaries needed. But what if I need to segment the design each API to a different person/s? Is that possible in a single APIM instance? Hope the question makes sense.

Comment: @JakeUT - For a single instance , did you check the standalone subscription? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions#subscriptions-for-all-apis-or-an-individual-api

Comment: The standalone subscription option seems make it possible to have a subscription not be tied to a developer account. I guess what I am looking for is where lets say Developer1 has ownership of API1, Developer2 has ownership of API2...without being able to make cross-changes. If I only had Developer1 who managed API1, API2, then no issues. But was looking to see if I could have separation.

Comment: In that case you can have the separation by the first method. You can create Group1 for Developer1 and Group2 for Developer2. While you are creating the product you can choose the group and the APIs accordingly. Say for ProductA you are selecting Group1 and API1. Now the group will be beneficial in case, in future, you need to give Developer3 to give access to API1. Then you can simply add Developer3 to Group1. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks for the response! But wouldn't that be limited to just who can view the API within the Developer Portal as a consumer? Will it separate them on the design of the API within the Azure Portal?

Comment: Yes, you are adding the group to the access control to restrict access to only that group. So yes it will work.

Comment: Thanks Jaya! So it does appear that this is doable. Also was reading that this is achievable via using a custom RBAC scope -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-role-based-access-control